# Angular2: get a pipe that selects from an array `|` a single object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6, akita

I have a bit of a complicated observable in Angular (courtesy of using Akita, I cannot change this), it's a `|`'ed Observable of either an array of `Dinosaur` objects, *or* a single `Dinosaur` object, or undefined:

```
import { QueryEntity } from "@datorama/akita";

export class DinosaurQuery extends QueryEntity<DinosaurState, Dinosaur> {
  activeDinosaurs$ = this.selectActive(); // Type: Observable<Dinosaur[]> | Observable<Dinosaur | undefined>

  constructor(protected store: DinosaursStore) {
    super(store);
  }
}
```

What I want to get from this, as an observable, is either the single object, *or* the first object in the array in case it is an array. Or undefined, if there is none.

```
export class DinosaurSelection {
    // I want singleSelectedDinosaur$ to be of type: Observable<Dinosaur | undefined>
    singleSelectedDinosaur$ = this.dinosaurQuery.activeDinosaurs$.pipe(???);

    constructor(protected dinosaurQuery: DinosaurQuery) {}

}
```

I presume there must be some pipe that does this, but I can't find something appropriate that can act on the `|` of an object and an array of that object at the same time. (Or maybe it can't be done with a pipe but in another way, that's also fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use "pipe(map)" to transform if is array

```
singleSelectedDinosaur$ = this.dinosaurQuery.activeDinosaurs$.pipe(
    map((res:any)=>{
       if (res && Array.isArray(res)) //if res and is array
          return res[0]   //return the first element
       return res;      //else resut res
    }
));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed what I'm looking for, but it's giving me an error:
`error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.` Any idea why that would be?

Comment: I can't see where the error there are, try `(res:any|any[])`

Comment: Still gives the same error... but oddly it does actually run correctly, so might be some compiler error level setting - I've marked the answer as Accepted. Could it be I'm missing some imports to have this work correctly? I have: 
`import { isArray } from "util";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";`

Comment: isArray is JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/isArray, so, you **has not need** import anything, "map" is an operator of 'rxjs/operators', so **you must** import map from 'rxjs/operators'

Comment: The remaining error turned out to be unrelated to this ticket. For completeness' sake it was a result of an issue described here: https://github.com/datorama/akita/issues/184
But can be ignored for the purposes of this question.